# SQL Server floating point numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if there is a way to show the values of columns of type floating point numbers in two decimal places in `SQL Server 2008` via settings? For instance, let say I have a table called orders with several columns. I want to be able to do the following:

`SELECT * FROM orders`

I expect to see any values in columns of type float to display with decimal notation; for instance, a value of `4` should display as `4.0` or `4.00`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "No".

SQL Server isn't really in the business of data presentation. We all do a lot of backbends from time to time to force things into a presentable state, and the other answers provided so far can help you on a column by column basis.

But the sort of "set it and forget it" thing you're looking for is better handled in a front end application.

Comment: Regarding the back-end solutions you mentioned, can you elaborate? Do you mean like having a trigger on tables that would execute a stored procedure  of some type that would preform some updates on the table data ?

Comment: Actually, I said "front end". :) If you're piping data to an application of some kind, that's usually a good place for making numeric presentations consistent, though, say, a style sheet for a web app or what have you. Not really my forte, though, so I'm not much real help there.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `CONVERT` function with `NUMERIC( x , 2)` for numeric values

( *where x is at least 3, better more, upto 38* )

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), 4 ) as "Dcm Nr(2)";

Dcm Nr(2)
---------
 4,00

SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 1), 4 ) as "Dcm Nr(1)";

Dcm Nr(1)
---------
 4,0
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest form of what happens to me is making a "cast", for example:

```
SELECT CAST(orders AS DECIMAL(10,2)) FROM [your table];
```